# Best way to handle "forgot password" in a stand alone application

Tags: android, passwords, forgot-password

As mentioned in the question, I'm trying to make an application that **has no interaction with a server**. The problem is that the user can use a password at some parts of the application and then starts the problems. The one problem that I really couldn't find much materials about is how to implement a local *forgot password* feature, which I think is essential.

**Storing the password locally without any kind of encryption and then retrieve it when needed isn't any option for many reasons** (password exposed to hackers and everyone who get theirs hands on the phone can retrieve it too).

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an answer to your comment, but never store the password, instead store a hash of it and compare against that. Anything your application encrypts and can decrypt can be decrypted by third parties (such as hackers) as well.

Comment: I know that, but if I don't store the password without encryption then I can't retrieve if the user loses it.. and as I already said this isn't an option.

Comment: Read answer below.  Never retrieve the password, just allow the user to reset it if they go through some pre-arranged (by them) steps.

Comment: I agree with ElJay that the password should never, ever, be retrieved. It should simply not even be possible.

Comment: If someone is going to the trouble and has the means of breaking 3DES level encryption, then they deserve that password :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the specifics about Android, but in iOS I have done this using security questions stored in `NSUserDefaults` (an application wide non-encrypted datastore) and then keeping the password and the security answers in the encrypted keychain.  When the questions have been answered, the user is prompted to change the password which is then updated in the keychain.

I would think Android would have similar features and methods.  I will know this answer better in about 6 months (I am making a commitment to learn Android next)

Comment: but this doesn't guaranty that the user will be able to reset his password(if he forgets the answer too for example). how did you cover this part? because if the pwd can't be changed the application is practically unusable!!

Comment: Then the user doesn't need to use the application.  I mean seriously, if the app is needing to be secured, then there is an expectation for the user to maintain some seriousness about the application.  I wrote an app for a hospital and there was a secure area there too.  We used this system and if the user just couldn't get in (we gave them 5 attempts), the data inside that area was wiped.  You can only do so much.

Comment: this is a bit disappointing, but I guess I knew it should be this way.. thank you any way